# Using same reference for multiple method parameters

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'll preface by saying I'm very new to Rust, and I'm still wrapping my head around the semantics of the borrow-checker. I have some understanding of why it doesn't like my code, but I'm not sure how to resolve it in an idiomatic way.

I have a method in Rust which accepts 3 parameters with a signature that looks something like this:

```
fn do_something(&mut self, mem: &mut impl TraitA, bus: &mut impl TraitB, int_lines: &impl TraitC) -> ()
```

I also have a `struct` which implements all three of these traits; however, the borrow-checker is complaining when I attempt to use the same reference for multiple parameters:

```
cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
```

And also:

```
cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
```

My first question is whether this is a shortcoming of the borrow-checker (being unable to recognize that the same reference is being passed), or by design (I suspect this is the case, since from the perspective of the called method each reference is distinct and thus the ownership of each can be regarded separately).

My second question is what the idiomatic approach would be. The two solutions I see are:

a) Combining all three traits into one. While this is technically trivial given my library's design, it would make the code decidedly less clean since the three traits are used to interface with unrelated parts of the `struct`'s state. Furthermore, since this is a library (the `do_something` method is part of a test), it hinders the possibility of separating the state out into separate `struct`s.

b) Moving each respective part of the `struct`'s state into separate `struct`s, which are then owned by the main `struct`. This seems like the better option to me, especially since it does not require any changes to the library code itself.

Please let me know if I'm missing another solution, or if there's a way to convince the borrow-checker to accept my original design.

Comment: The borrow-checker blocking you is by design: mutable borrows are exclusive. This explicitly violates that rule. Without more specifics, option B certainly sounds the best to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The borrow checker is operating as designed. It only knows you are passing three different mutable references into the same function: it does not know what the function will do with these, even if they do happen to be references to the same struct. Within the function they are three different mutable references to the same struct.

If the three different traits represent three different functional aspects, then your best approach might be to split the struct into different structs, each implementing one of the traits, as you have proposed.

If you would prefer to keep a single struct, and if the function will always be called with a single struct, then you can just pass it in once like this:

```
fn do_something(&mut self, proc: &mut (impl TraitA + TraitB + TraitC)) -> () { ... }
```